# SQL server and .NET memory constraints, allocations, and garbage collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running .NET 3.5 (C#) and SQL Server 2005 (for our clients).  The code that we run does some regression math and is a little complicated.  I get the following error when I run multiple pages on our site:

```
.NET Framework execution was aborted by escalation policy because of out of memory. 
System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
System.InvalidOperationException:
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the root cause of this: is it a database issue or my C## code? or is it concurrency with locks when running queries? or somethin else?

The code is erroring here:

```
erver.ScriptTimeout = 300;
        string returnCode = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDll"].ToString())) {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection)) {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandTimeout = 300;
                returnCode = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                //Dispose();
            }
            //Dispose();
        }
```

Our contractor wrote a bunch of code to help with SQL connections in an App_Code/sqlHelper.s file. Some of them are like this:

```
public static SqlDataReader GetDataReader(string sql, string connectionString, int connectionTime) {
        lock (_lock) {
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = GetConnection(connectionString);
                //connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = connectionTime;
                    WriteDebugInfo("GetDataReader", sql);
                    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Dispose();
                throw new DataException(sql, connectionString, e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Should there be some deallocation of memory somewhere?

Comment: are you closing your connections?

Comment: Please provide your codes so that everyone can check.

Comment: just noticed that dispose was commented out too

Comment: look for a call to ExecuteReader. The problem isn't in this code.

Comment: updated the code, seems to me that its not getting deallocated correctly?

Comment: Why is there a lock object in the SqlDataReader?  I don't see a reason for it, this all looks thread safe.  In fact, that would only kill concurrency AFAIK, especially on long-running queries.  What does GetConnection do?

Comment: GetConnection just grabs the connection string and return a connection

Comment: yeah i'll try to remove the locks and rerun, i'm also thinking the after every GetDataReader call in the code, that once data is return into a string to run Dispose(). Is that a good idea?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, but I suppose it couldn't hurt.  I never did it my data layers; it's done automatically.  Dispose is typically only needed for IO-type tasks like files and memory buffers and the like.   IIRC, SqlDataReader is a fast, forward-only server side cursor, so it shouldn't be sucking up too much memory.  OTOH, if you were downloading a million rows into a dataset, then I'd be concerned :)

Comment: BTW, +1 to what the below answer said...make sure your SqlDataReaders are being explicitly closed

Comment: okay, yeah its definitely a memory issue too, since the site slows and stops then gets better when garabage collection runs. Besides its statistics stuff that we run so its hundreads and thousands of rows in the sql statements.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, for some reason, your DataReader isn't being closed. An exception? The method user didn't remember to close the DataReader?

A function that returns a DataReader to be used outside its body leaves the responsibility of closing it to outer code, so there's no guarantee that the Reader will be closed. If you don't close the reader, you cannot reuse the connection in which it was opened.

**So returning a DataReader from a function is a very bad idea!**

You can see a whole discussion on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506919/closing-sqldatareaders-how-to-tell-if-they-are-closed/10507254#10507254).

Look for the usages of this function (`GetDataReader`), and check if there's guarantee that the reader is getting closed. And, most importantly, that there is no possibility that this code re-enters and uses the same collection to open a new DataReader before the first is closed. (Don't be mislead by the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection. This only takes care of closing the connection when the DataReader is closed... only if you don't fail to close it)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your data reader is already filled in. Its always a better way to release the data reader, command , data set , data table and close the connection in finally block.
Make use of Dispose() and Close() methods .