# Multi threading of process in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, sql-server-2005

I have the following code that runs to start my table calculations (the table calculations fire off a few queries returning thousands of rows). When my app just runs one instance, things are fine, but 2 or more then the server slows done and I start to get errors.

Should I turn this code into threads? How is that done?

```
private static object _lock = new object();

private void RunTable(string outputType, string _outputDataType) {

        Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;

        string returnCode = string.Empty;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDll"].ToString()))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandTimeout = 300;
                    returnCode = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                    Dispose();
                }
                Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: First: if you're seeing errors, then tell us what error you're seeing. Second: how much data are you reading (i.e. can you load all the data in RAM)?

Comment: For quick, simple and efficient multithreading, you can make use of the BackgroundWorker Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx but my guess is that you may have some issues with the way you query the database, or perhaps you need some SQL tuning.

Comment: when you say "one instance / two instances" you mean processes or threads?

Comment: the errors are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712860/deallocation-of-sqldatareader

Comment: What is `Dispose()` doing there by itself? Surely that is not correct! The good thing with `using` is you don't even need to manually call the `command.Dispose`/`connection.Dispose` (see what I did there?) methods in this case. Omit it.

Comment: @chris The errors you showed in the other question don't seem to correspond to any of the code you have here.

Comment: @lirik yes but as you see in the other ticket, the error happens on this line" returnCode = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL server and .NET memory constraints, allocations, and garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712055/sql-server-and-net-memory-constraints-allocations-and-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 1):

First: if you're seeing errors, then tell us what error you're seeing.

Second: how much data are you reading (i.e. can you load all the data in RAM)?

Third: if you can't load all the data at once, then try using the `SqlDataReader` to continuously read from the database.

Regarding the multithreading: it really depends on where is your bottleneck. If your bottleneck is in reading from the database, then you won't gain much by multithreading it (especially if your database does not allow concurrent access). You **can** use threads to process the data once it has been obtained from the database and that works particularly well when you have to use an `SqlDataReader` since you're reading record by record.

Comment: the errors are fully listed in another ticket as seen in the comments above

Comment: OK, so somebody has already answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712055/sql-server-and-net-memory-constraints-allocations-and-garbage-collection How many times are you posting it? You have another method that gets the `SqlDataReader` and you're keeping it open... fix that problem and let us know if it gets better.

Comment: i have SqlDataReader reader and it works but I do reader.Close() after ALL of them and still get that error. Its something with multi processes and not dealocating the memory

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with a very simple example and eliminate all the "external" issues which are not relevant to the problem. Multithreading could be a problem if another thread tries to create an `SqlDataReader` before the currently open one is closed. Make sure that you synchronize properly when using multiple threads and multiple `SqlDataReaders` (i.e. only one should be open at a time).